# How to create a non visual component without any icon on the form?

Tags: delphi

I would like to create a non visual component (like `TTimer` for example) that I can drop on the form and that I can set up directly from the Object Inspector, but I don't want to see its icon on the form (it'd just obstruct anything). For example `TFloatAnimation` works like this but I don't understand how.

Comment: Both of those discussions are dealing with *visual* controls, hiding their rendered UIs from the Designer.  More importantly, the flags mentioned are for VCL only. `TFloatAnimation` is a FMX component, it doesn't have those flags available. And the discussions don't touch on the behavior of icons for *non-visual* components at all.

Comment: The IDE contains a menu function you can add to the toolbar that allows you to show/hide non visual components at design-time. If you can't see an icon, you can't click on it to see it's properties.

Comment: @nolaspeaker:  Good point, but you could look for and select the component in the Object inspector's component drop-down list (or in the SStructure pane).

Comment: VCL or FMX? Any answer would require that information, and you've not provided a tag to indicate which you're targeting. Your example (TFloatAnimation) is FMX-only. There are no VCL components that I'm aware of that work in the same way.

Answer (score 2):

The GExperts library (http://www.gexperts.org/) has a plug-in which can toggle the visibility
of non-visual components on a form, and it is *apparently* not Delphi-version-specific but it is
not exactly trivial.

The method which does this is

```
    procedure THideNonVisualCompsExpert.ToggleNonVisualVisible(Form: TCustomForm);
    const
      NonVisualClassName = 'TContainer';
    var
      VisibleState: Boolean;
      FormHandle: THandle;
      CompHandle: THandle;
      WindowClass: string;
      FirstCompFound: Boolean;
      WinControl: TWinControl;
      ChildControl: TWinControl;
      i: Integer;
    begin
      Assert(Assigned(Form));
      Assert(Form.Handle > 0);
      FirstCompFound := False;
      WinControl := Form;
      if InheritsFromClass(WinControl.ClassType, 'TWinControlForm') then
      begin
        for i := WinControl.ComponentCount - 1 downto 0 do
        begin
          if WinControl.Controls[i] is TWinControl then
          begin
            ChildControl := WinControl.Controls[i] as TWinControl;
            if InheritsFromClass(ChildControl.ClassType, 'TCustomFrame') then
            begin
              WinControl := ChildControl;
              Break;
            end;
          end;
        end;
      end;

      FormHandle := GetWindow(WinControl.Handle, GW_CHILD);
      CompHandle := GetWindow(FormHandle, GW_HWNDLAST);
      VisibleState := False;
      GxOtaClearSelectionOnCurrentForm;

      while (CompHandle <> 0) do
      begin
        WindowClass := GetWindowClassName(CompHandle);
        if AnsiSameText(WindowClass, NonVisualClassName) then
        begin
          if not FirstCompFound then
          begin
            VisibleState := not IsWindowVisible(CompHandle);
            FirstCompFound := True;
          end;
          if VisibleState then
            ShowWindow(CompHandle, SW_SHOW)
          else
            ShowWindow(CompHandle, SW_HIDE);
        end;
        CompHandle := GetWindow(CompHandle, GW_HWNDPREV);
      end;
    end;
```

in the unit GX_HideNonVisualComps.Pas.

As written, it toggles the visibility of all the non-visual components on the
target form, but looking at the code of the `ToggleNonVisualVisible` method it looks like it
*ought* to be possible (but I have not tried) to adapt it to operate on a selected component class and
force instances of the class to a non-visible state.  Once you have done that, you would probably
need to experiment with how and when to invoke the method at design-time; if I was doing it, I would probably start
with somewhere like the target component's `Loaded` method.

(I would feel more comfortable posting this "answer" as a comment but obviously it would be too long)

Answer (score 1):

I have thought about this.  A Non Visual Component does not do any painting, in a Windows environment (like the IDE) it has no Window, and therefore cannot influence how the IDE chooses to render it.

One approach would be to derive from TWinControl, making your component a Visual Component, and then to ensure that it is not drawn.  Try setting the positioning properties to be non-published, and when you are parented, always set your position outside the parent window.  This means that your control is always clipped and never painted.

I haven't tried this, but I can see no reason why it wouldn't work.

You can also use this approach to have an apparently non visual component that renders information in the IDE at designtime, but not at runtime.